# Gravitational wave propagating in $x$-$y$ plane with angle $\theta$ with $x$-axis

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, rotation

I am going to ask a question related to a paper called "Spin angular momentum of gravitational wave interference" which its link is: https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/abf23f. My question is about the form of the polarization when GW (Gravitational wave) propagates in the x-y plane with angle $\theta$ with the x-axis (the relation 14 of the paper mentioned). What I know about this subject tells me that we know linearized GW in empty space has two polarization and due to the shape of changing distance in the space-time, people call them $h_{+}$ and $h_{\times}$.So when GW propagates along x axis we have:
$h_{ij}=\left[\matrix{0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0& h_{+}& h_{\times}\cr 0&h_{\times}&-h_{+} }\right]\tag{1}$ in this way I have got the relation 13 in my pocket. If I want to derive a GW in the x-y plane with angle $\theta$ with x axis I will sandwich the above polarization between two $J_{z} $ matrix of $SO(3)$ so I have :
$$ (J_{z})^T  h_{ij} ( J_{z})=\left[\matrix{\sin(\theta)^2 h_{+} & -\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)h_{+}  & -\sin(\theta) h_{\times} \cr -\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)h_{+}& \cos(\theta)^2 h_{+}& \cos(\theta)h_{\times}\cr -\sin(\theta) h_{\times}&\cos(\theta)h_{\times}&-h_{+} }\right]\tag{2} $$ Now my question: I would be very grateful if anybody can tell me why relation-14 in the paper has this strange form. I can not understand it.This strange relation is:$$\left[\matrix{\sin(\theta)^2 h_{+} & -\frac{3}{2}\sin(2\theta)h_{+}  & -\sin(\theta) h_{\times} \cr -\frac{3}{2}\sin(2\theta)h_{+}& \cos(\theta)^2 h_{+}& \cos(\theta)^2 h_{\times}\cr -\sin(\theta) h_{\times}&\cos(\theta)^ 2h_{\times}&-h_{+} }\right]\tag{3}$$

Comment: I agree with your result, to me it seems like a typo. I think you could try contacting the authors to point this out.

Comment: @Mateo, there is something strange. with both matrices the results are the same. It is confusing why it is so. Thank you very much for your time given.

Comment: Which result turns out to be the same?

Comment: The results of the paper mentioned (computing spin angular momentum) are the same for both interference.I mean this result for my matrix is the same as the result when using the matrix in the paper.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really go through the whole paper. They claim to use (13) and (14), and insert it into (5). I've checked that and the results for (5) are not the same if your matrix (2) or (3) is used.